# Click on Tab bar calls the Tap Gesture in iOS

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview, tabs

I am new to iOS development and facing a strange problem.

I am developing a tabbed iOS app. In one of the tab it loads a `UIWebView`. I have added a tap gesture on `UIImageView` and add it in `UIScrollView`. This `UIScrollView` is part of `UIWebView`. Tap gesture opens up a keyboard.

The problem is that when I comes to this tab and try to navigate to another tab it opens up the keyboard on tab click instead of moving to the clicked tab. Means the tap gesture is calling on tab click as well. When I scroll the web view to top so that it will no more remains before tab then it works properly.

I am adding tap gesture on `UIImageView` in following way.

```
-(void)setOnTypeGesture{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *uiViewTextViewGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedInUIView:)];
    uiView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [uiView addGestureRecognizer:uiViewTextViewGesture];
    [uiViewTextViewGesture release];

}
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Show the code where you are adding the tap gesture.

Comment: @sooper I have updated the question. Please read it again there is a UIImageView in the middle as well.

Comment: What is the uiView instance variable pointing to. Also, to check it out correctly, you can put some back ground color on the scroll view etc, so that you are sure that the view is not on top of the tab bar.

Comment: @Srikanth uiView is the instance of UIImageView. I have tried the gray background color as well and it shows the tabs in front of all the views.

Comment: "When I scroll the web view to top so that it will no more remains before tab then it works properly." - Not sure what you mean here. Is the webview overlapping the tabs.

Comment: @Srikanth no webview is not overlapping the tabs. I mean to say that when i scroll the webview so that it reaches at the end of webview the tab starts working.

Comment: Try setting the `clipsToBounds` property of your `UIImageView` and `UIScrollView` to `YES` before adding the gesture.

Comment: uiView.userInteractionEnabled = YES; remove this line from your code and try again.

Comment: @sooper I have set clipsToBounds to YES for both views but it doesn't worked.

Comment: @R.A I want to set uiView.userInteractionEnabled = YES so that I can catch tap events to open keyboard. When I remove uiView.userInteractionEnabled = YES the tabs worked but the tap gesture doesn't call even if I click on the `UIImageView` .